# Getting unique device ID in VS2012 Windows 8 Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am new to Windows 8 Store Apps, and need to fetch device ID in one of my XAML project. And this device ID should be unique. I searched the internet and came across 2 different ways.

First way in C# code,

```
private string GetHardwareId()
{
    var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

Second way in C# code,

```
var easClientDeviceInformation = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation()
GUID deviceId = easClientDeviceInformation.Id;
```

The first one gives in bits format whereas second one gives GUID. I am not getting any idea that which is correct one.

I referred this [blog](http://www.wadewegner.com/2012/09/getting-the-application-id-and-hardware-id-in-windows-store-applications/)

And MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id) too.

Can any one guide me regarding which can be used as Device ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UDID for windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893746/udid-for-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

I had same confusion, but finally used `HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken`.
Because I find no information about uniqueness of `EasClientDeviceInformation.ID`

However, you can't use `ID` returned by `HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken` as it is, because it depends upon many hardware components. And if any one of them changed, a different id will be returned.

There is more information at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In VS2013, Microsoft uses the following method to retrieve the unique "installation id" or "device id" for the current device when uploading a channel URI retrieved from the Microsoft Push Notification Server (MPNS) to implement Push Notification:

```
var token = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
string installationId = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(token.Id);
```