# Getting OS, Platform and Device information on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

How do I get the following information on Windows 8?

Platform, OS version, device name, device ID and carrier (not sure if carrier is applicable to Windows 8)

With Windows Phone 8, I retrieve them using:

```
Platform: Environment.OSVersion.Platform
OS Version: Environment.OSVersion.Version
Device name: Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName
Device ID: Windows.Phone.System.Analytics.HostInformation.PublisherHostId
Carrier: Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator
```

I am looking for the Windows 8 equivalent of the above Windows Phone 8 information using C#.

Comment: Desktop or Windows Store app?

Comment: Good question, it is Windows Store.

Comment: OSversion = "windows 8" ;-)

Comment: FYI: `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName` Phone seems unavailable in my universal app project

Answer (score 3):

You can get below information from [here](https://gist.github.com/HamGuy/8294463)

- Windows Version
- Processor Architecture
- Device Category
- Device Manufacturer
- Device Model

For unique ID, see [UDID for windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893746/udid-for-windows-8)

You can get below information from [here](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/blob/master/Q42.WinRT/Util.cs)

- App Version
- OS Version
- Machine Name

Comment: Code from attackpattern is uncompilable for an XAML app. The auto/await thing is illegal.

Comment: The code from attachpattern is missing return types. Check out my updated answer with workable code.

Comment: Copying code from somewhere and stripping off the attribution and copyright notice is lame.

Comment: I didn't copy. I post the code because the reference site may get down. Then there is no meaning of site. Though added copyright notice.

Comment: I've found the copy of attack pattern's code. Answer is updated. You can check out [here](https://gist.github.com/HamGuy/8294463)

Answer (score 1):

I only got ItemNameKey, ModelNameKey, ManufacturerKey, to work or the ones without hex numbers. The others don't, dunno why. This is working code but in C++, and since there's nothing on the matter in C++/CX, I'm posting it here (took a while to figure out even what namespaces are used in C# and took about an hour to figure out how to write anything derivable & working off Collections::Iterable and Collections::Iterator in C++)

```
using namespace Windows::System;
//using namespace Windows::System::L.Linq;
using namespace Windows::System::Threading;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration::Pnp;
 using namespace Collections;
//public class SystemInfoEstimate
//{

Platform::Array< Platform::String ^> ^StrArray;// = ref new Platform::Array< Platform::String ^>(1);

ref class MyIterator sealed: IIterator<Platform::String ^>
{
    int Index;
    public:
    MyIterator()
    {
        Index = 0;
    }


    property virtual Platform::String ^ Current 
    { 
       Platform::String ^ get()
       {
           return StrArray->get( Index );
       }
    }   
    property virtual bool HasCurrent 
    { 
       bool get()
       {
           return true;
       }
    }
    virtual bool MoveNext()
    {
        Index++;
        if (Index >=StrArray->Length)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    virtual unsigned int GetMany( Platform::WriteOnlyArray<Platform::String ^> ^Arr)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<StrArray->Length; i++)
        {           
            Arr->set( i, StrArray[i] );
        }
        return StrArray->Length;
    }
};
ref class MyIterable sealed: IIterable<Platform::String ^>
{
public:
    virtual IIterator<Platform::String ^> ^First()
    {
        return ref new MyIterator();//StrArray[0];
    }
};

    Platform::String ^ItemNameKey = "System.ItemNameDisplay";
    Platform::String ^ ModelNameKey = "System.Devices.ModelName";
    Platform::String ^ ManufacturerKey = "System.Devices.Manufacturer";
    Platform::String ^ DeviceClassKey = "{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0},10";
    Platform::String ^ PrimaryCategoryKey = "{78C34FC8-104A-4ACA-9EA4-524D52996E57},97";
    Platform::String ^ DeviceDriverVersionKey = "{A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6},3";
    Platform::String ^ RootContainer = "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}";
    Platform::String ^ RootQuery = "System.Devices.ContainerId:=\"" + RootContainer + "\"";
    Platform::String ^ HalDeviceClass = "4d36e966-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318";

void GetSystemInfo()
{
    //return;
    StrArray = ref new Platform::Array< Platform::String ^>(2);
    MyIterable^ MI = ref new MyIterable();
    StrArray->set( 0, ModelNameKey );//ManufacturerKey );
    StrArray->set( 1, ManufacturerKey );
    auto v = create_task( PnpObject::CreateFromIdAsync(PnpObjectType::DeviceContainer, RootContainer, MI )//StrArray);
        );
    v.wait();
    PnpObject ^Ret = v.get();
    UINT Size = Ret->Properties->Size;
    if (Size > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<StrArray->Length; i++)
        {
            IIterator< IKeyValuePair< Platform::String ^, Platform::Object ^>^ > ^ It = Ret->Properties->First();

            bool Moving = true;
            while(Moving)
            {
                Platform::String ^PropStr = It->Current->Value->ToString();
                            //You could put OutputDebugString here ^
                Moving = It->MoveNext();
            }            
        }
    }    
 }
```