# Device Unique id in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How to get the device unique id in Windows Phone 8.1? The old way of using `DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")` does not work for Windows Universal app.

Comment: Any examples? I'm asking this question here, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004003/windows-phone-device-unique-id

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note that when you write Universal App, it can be installed not only on phone. While on Phone technically hardware configuration is the same, on other devices it can change and so its ID. That's I think there is no such universal method to get ID. (more information you can find [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893863/2681948)).

You may have a look at [HardwareIdentification class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.aspx) and its method [GetPackageSpecificToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx):

```
HardwareToken myToken = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
IBuffer hardwareId = myToken.Id;
```

There is also a [Guidance on using the App Specific Hardware ID (ASHWID) to implement per-device app logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).

Comment: If you want to use it you must remember, that this Id will change when you change the app signing certificate

Comment: @Johniak Thank you for poniting that out.

Comment: @Romasz `HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken` is dependent on Package id/name. Is there any other ID which appears same for all apps installed on same device?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I'm not sure about such one.

Comment: @Romasz Can you confirm whether it will unique for each device( i.e if I install same app in two devices, I will get different hardware id ) ? Also, if both devices are same then also we will get different hardware id?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I don't know.

Answer (score 32):

```
private string GetDeviceID()
{
    HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;

    HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
    IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);

     string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
     return hashedString;
}
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Why MD5 though? Why not any other algorithm??

Comment: I would replace "MD5" to [HashAlgorithmNames.Md5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmnames.md5.aspx).

Comment: You can replace CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString with Convert.ToBase64String, it will produce shorter but still readable string.