# Windows Phone 8.1: DeviceExtendedProperties or DeviceStatus for Device Unique ID

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, device, unique-id

I want to get the Device ID in Windows Phone **8.1**.

The [DeviceExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [DeviceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) are not available in WP8.1 (there is no `Microsoft.Phone.Info` namespace). I've just found the `EasClientDeviceInformation` class that I can't get the `Id` from it. There is an exception in the `Id` property:

[image]

And other properties are't unique.

There is another solution here but I don't know if it is safe or reliable to use: (?)
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/23537207/3682369

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `GetPackageSpecificToken()`. I have looked into it and haven't found any other way. Although MSDN says that the `Id` property contains some hardware info, it's actually an unique value for any device, even of the same model. So you can use it to identify the user's device.

This is how I use it in my application. Feel free to use my code:

```
private string GetDeviceId()
{
    var token = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: Good answer, and it works perfectly. But the returned ID is NOT the same as IMEI. Do you know what is the difference between this ID and the IMEI?

Comment: @AhmedKarim That is very likely to be a hashed IMEI, but no one knows for sure.

Comment: OK, but is it really unique and can I consider that it will be always unique for each device?

Comment: @AhmedKarim I'm pretty sure it is as long as it's being used by ads providers.