# DeviceExtendedProperties in C# - Microsoft.Phone.Info name space

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

On Windows Phone 8.1, in an C# project, I want to get the device ID via -> DeviceExtendedProperties
So I might want to do it like

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
```

or

```
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
```

The problem is, either way didn't compile,
I don't know what I'm missing.
It says it was supported in WP8.1

This is the error when I use the name space at the top of the file:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Same error when I call the function directly

```
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
```

Comment: If you would like to get useful answers it helps to actually be very thorough when asking your question. A phrase like "didn't pass compile" does not inform us about what the problem is. Please make sure you add the full text of the error to your question.

Comment: Fixed grammar. Removed smiley faces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1: DeviceExtendedProperties or DeviceStatus for Device Unique ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601993/windows-phone-8-1-deviceextendedproperties-or-devicestatus-for-device-unique-id) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23321484/2681948)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer,
Add the namespace at object browser.

anyway, thank you guys for the answer.