# Device ID in a UWP app (threshold 1)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

In Phone 8.1 you could get the device ID using [HardwareIdentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321484/device-unique-id-in-windows-phone-8-1/23322202#23322202), and even though the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.aspx) says it exists for Desktop apps, it does not exist for a UWP app.

[image: Screenshot of hardware profile not existing]

What is the alternative or a way to get a hardware ID for a UWP?

Comment: It doesn't imply it exists if you're targeting Universal Apps (only mobile and desktop). It's reasonable because HardwareIdentification isn't available for all UWP supported targets.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you are right. I don't agree with reasonable though - every device should have a unique ID. Can't think of one that can't have one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're running into a common issue when migrating an app from `Windows (Phone) 8(.1)` to the `Windows Universal Platform`.

The reason you're not seeing the `HardwareIdentification` is pretty simple: You don't reference the required sources!

You only see `AnalyticsInfo` and `AnalyticsVersionInfo`. This is because they are part of the **Universal** *Device Family*, as stated on the documentation page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.aspx) at the very bottom.

The `HardwareIdentification` however is not part of the **Universal** *Device Family*, it's part of the `Desktop` and `Mobile` family, as Adriano alread stated in his comment.

To make the info available, you have to add the references to the specific extensions:
[image]

After that, make sure to check if the type exists, before calling it:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation
    .IsTypePresent("Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification"))
```