# Windows Phone Device Unique Id

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone 7 app which is live in store which is using `DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")` to fetch id and I am updating it in store with new windows phone 8 app and using same method.

In both cases I am getting different id? I want the id to be same in both the cases.

Comment: Have you checked `WMAppManifest.xml -> Capabilities tab ->` switch on `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lighthouse/2013/08/27/how-to-get-unique-device-id-for-windows-8-and-windows-phone-app/):

> For Windows Phone 8 apps running on Windows Phone 8 devices and later, the DeviceUniqueId value is unique per device and per app publisher, which means that two apps published by different windows phone store account won’t get the same “device unique id”.

As there is a compatibility issue for Windows Phone 7.x apps, it may be the case that the phone essentially has an id for 7.x apps, and defers to a different logic to return a per publisher version for 8.x apps

Comment: yes u might be correct. It gives different device id for windows phone 7 and windows phone 8 for the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
byte[] id = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.
                DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
string deviceID = Convert.ToBase64String(id);
```

Checked `WMAppManifest.xml -> Capabilities tab ->` switch on `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE`

Comment: ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE is enabled.Issue is getting different id for win 7 app and win 8 app

Comment: id is dependence on phone, so Are you using same phone to generate id ?

Comment: yes same phone but first time with windows 7 app and second time wid windows 8 app.