# Windows IOT - Questions regarding MAC & saving/loading files

Tags: c#, windows, iot

so i'm currently under a internship working on a Raspberry Pi to modulate IO signals yadayadayada.

I've noticed a few weird things when it comes to IoT.
The OS is just scrapes of one and lacks lots of stuff that we devs use.
Such as, the system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface namespace.
Which i'd like to use to get my systems MAC-Adress.
One other issue i came across was that i can't really seem to find the right access to save/load and modify files locally on the device.
Any tips or tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different thread about Mac addresses here that may help you:

[C# - Get mac address in Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097870/c-sharp-get-mac-address-in-universal-apps)

For saving/loading files, are you using **Windows.Storage.KnownFolders** ? That could help you. Just arbitrarily saving files outside of the known folders structure could be a challenge.

Comment: Tried the windows.storage format, it seems to work however the task that i 'm running it inside is not that helpful atm. Currently working on it tho.

Comment: Got it to work! Thank you so much for the Windows.Storage tip :)

Comment: Would you mind helping me with loading the newest file? So far i've tried to open it through listing all files, order by date and then pick the newest one, without much success :/