# How to get mac address

Tags: c++, uwp, hololens, cppwinrt

i'm working on a uwp app runing on hololens2, i want get the wifi mac address.

according to this documents: [Windows.Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking?view=winrt-22000), i wrote this code.

```
 // part of includes at pch.h
 #include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Devices.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Devices.WiFi.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Sms.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Connectivity.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Proximity.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.ServiceDiscovery.Dnssd.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Sockets.h>
 #include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Vpn.h>
```

```
 // some cpp function
    
     void MainPage::ClickLoginHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
     {
         using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections;
         using namespace winrt::Windows::Networking;
         using namespace winrt::Windows::Networking::Connectivity;
         using namespace winrt::Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators;
         ConnectionProfile profile = NetworkInformation::GetInternetConnectionProfile();
         NetworkOperatorTetheringManager manager = 
NetworkOperatorTetheringManager::CreateFromConnectionProfile(profile); // error on the line
         IVectorView<NetworkOperatorTetheringClient> clients = manager.GetTetheringClients();
         for (NetworkOperatorTetheringClient client : clients)
         {
             OutputDebugString(client.MacAddress().c_str());
             OutputDebugString(L"\r\n");
         }
     }
```

but it reports an error: WinRT originate error - 0x8007007F : 'The specified procedure could not be found.'。

it seems missing dll, and i can not found out which one, or two?

if you know that please let me know.

if you know other way to get mac address, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Derive from document it looks need to add [`wiFiControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringClient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22000#windows-requirements) capability. Have you enabled it?

Comment: yes, i added it in Package.appxmanifest, or reports access denied, diffrent situation.@NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Have you tested within desktop? Does it only occur in hololens2 device?

Comment: maybe. i will test. but i have to get mac in hololens2 finally.

Comment: Well. you could also use pinvoke method GetAdaptersInfo to approach. please try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098615/7254781).

Comment: Ok, good may I  convert it as answer for this thread?

Comment: of course, just convert it.

Comment: Have you actually verified that you can call [`GetAdaptersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.markup.ixamlmetadataprovider) from a program targeting the UWP? It's documented to be available for *"desktop apps only"*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How to get mac address for hololens2.

For this scenario, you could use [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) method to approach. The document has [simple code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses#examples) that you could refer.